# How do I define a function to extract values from nested dictionary for each row in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a column named 'urls' in dataframe 'df' that each row consists of nested dictionaries with a URL and whether it is malicious or not. I'd like to extract only the value of the nested dictionary for each row.

```
0    {'url example 1': {'malicious': False}}
1    {'url example 2': {'malicious': False}}
```

By defining a function, I'd like to use 'apply' function to get the result for each row.

Here's the sample function that I have defined.

```
def urlconcern(url):
    try:
        r = s.lookup_urls([url]) 
        return r.values()
    except:
        pass
```

After running this with 'apply' function

```
df['urls'].apply(urlconcern)
```

This only gives the result below with round bracket (strangely)

```
0    ({'malicious': False})
1    ({'malicious': False})
```

**The desired answer would be**

```
False
False
```

Could there be any way to do so?

Comment: Can you show how you current use `urlconcern` in an apply call (giving the result you show)?

Comment: Is this related to Pandas? Please add appropriate tags and also please make sure you are posting a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given pandas series `s` (I'm assuming it's a pandas series)

```
s = pd.Series([{'url example 1': {'malicious': False}},
               {'url example 2': {'malicious': False}}])
```

you can use generator expression inside `next` to look for values of nested dicts.

```
out = s.apply(lambda url: next((v for d in url.values() for k,v in d.items()), None))
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
dtype: bool
```

However, I'm not convinced this is what you're looking for since you're losing the url info here.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a pandas dataframe? Did you instantiate it? You may want to look at how this dictionary is constructed because it should be more like

```
>>> df = {'url':['url example 1', 'url example 2', 'url example 3'], 'malicious': [False, False, True]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(df)
>>> df
             url  malicious
0  url example 1      False
1  url example 2      False
2  url example 3       True
```

Then do

```
>>> df[df['malicious'] == False]
             url  malicious
0  url example 1      False
1  url example 2      False
```

I know this doesn't answer your question exactly, but it's a standard way of working with DataFrames and should help your workflow later down the line.